# Where does bot framework stores dialog stack

Tags: botframework

Where does bot framework stores dialog stack? My bot started to act strangely since couple of days. It seems that the bot is stuck in a dialog and is not willing to let go whatever the user says. Even resetting the stack doesn't work.

Does the dialog stack has to do something with the bot state service? Which will be soon deprecated?

Comment: What kind of strange behavior ?

Comment: @AkshayTilekar Sometimes the bot is not responding at all. Sometimes it keep asking for a particular input,even after stack reset.

Comment: Where it is deployed and What did the log says ?

Comment: are u using C # or node?

Comment: @AkshayTilekar Bot is deployed in azure. Which log do you mean?

Comment: @EzequielJadib I am using c#

Comment: try sending a `/deleteprofile` message

Comment: Please show your code so can we try to reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved after implementing custom state service with Azure Cosmos DB as described here. - [Manage custom state data with Azure Cosmos DB for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state-azure-cosmosdb)

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).